# Unable to install conda spyder package build

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I want to install a specific build of spyder on conda - version 3.3.0 with py36_a build.

```
# Name                  Version           Build  Channel                             
spyder                    3.3.0          py27_0  pkgs/main           
spyder                    3.3.0          py36_0  pkgs/main           
spyder                    3.3.0          py37_0  pkgs/main           
spyder                    3.3.1          py27_1  pkgs/main           
spyder                    3.3.1          py35_1  pkgs/main           
spyder                    3.3.1          py36_1  pkgs/main           
spyder                    3.3.1          py37_1  pkgs/main
```

But when I do, I get an error that the package has not been found.

```
$conda install spyder=3.3.0=py36_1
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - spyder==3.3.0=py36_1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

I also tried `conda install -c pkgs/main spyder=3.3.0=py36_1` but it gave me the same error. What's wrong here?

Comment: You say you want to install 3.3.1, but you're trying to install 3.3.0...

Comment: Sorry. That's a mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: Then the output of the conda-list command is clear - that package doesn't exist. Why do you think you can install this version based on the output there?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really recommended, 
and updating one or more dependencies to a version not tested together in the anaconda meta package is the likely reason for this problem in the first place.

However, the fact that updating,.. something...is requiring Spyder>=3.3.0 is worrisome, and seems to match what was reported on another thread. Could you please run

```
conda install spyder=3.3.0
```

and post your full output here, We need to know what's causing this issue.

And also dont't try to doing `conda update --all`.

Instead, you need to do below

```
conda remove spyder-kernels
conda install spyder-kernel==0.*
conda update spyder
```

My suggestion is simply to update the packages that you an update for:

`conda update spyder, conda update pandas`, etc.